# Помогите с регулярными выражениями

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, list

```
import re

def sanitize_phone_number(phone):
    phone = [re.sub('\D', '', digit)
             for digit in [phone_number
             for phone_number in phone]] # тут пробовал добавить if digit.isdigit()
    print(phone)
    return phone


uneditted_numbers = ['', '', '', '', '', '3', '8', '', '0', '5', '0', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '3', '2', '', '3', '4']

sanitize_phone_number(uneditted_numbers)
```

Я уже сделал шаблон для ввода1:

```
    "    +38(050)123-32-34    ",
    "     0503451234",
    "   ( 050   )8889900",
    "38050-111-22-22",
    "38050 111 22 11   "
```

Но моя программа не может справится с вводом в примере. Как мне вывести целый номер без пропусков одним элементом? Уже несколько часов не могу найти решения. Если добавляю `digit.isdigit()` для ввода в коде, то при `ввод1` уже выводит пустые списки...

Comment: "".join(uneditted_numbers)  не вариант ?

Comment: К сожалению, расчет идет что пользователь может ввести любые данные. Поэтому в функции нужно обрабатывать ввод из отрывка и ввод1

Comment: а как пользователь введёт список ? инпут принимает только строки. или откуда вы эти данные  принимаете ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```py
import re

def sanitize_phone_number(phone: str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r'\D', '', phone)

items = [
    " +38(050)123-32-34 ", " 0503451234", " ( 050 )8889900", "38050-111-22-22", "38050 111 22 11 ",
    "'', '', '', '', '', '3', '8', '', '0', '5', '0', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '3', '2', '', '3', '4'"
]
for phone in items:
    new_phone = sanitize_phone_number(phone)
    print(f'{phone!r} -> {new_phone!r}')
```

Результат:

```
' +38(050)123-32-34 ' -> '380501233234'
' 0503451234' -> '0503451234'
' ( 050 )8889900' -> '0508889900'
'38050-111-22-22' -> '380501112222'
'38050 111 22 11 ' -> '380501112211'
"'', '', '', '', '', '3', '8', '', '0', '5', '0', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '3', '2', '', '3', '4'" -> '380501233234'
```

Comment: Но у меня же ввод: '', '', '', '', '', '3', '8', '', '0', '5', '0', '', '1', '2', '3', '', '3', '2', '', '3', '4'
Нужно сделать '380501233234'

Comment: @Pain, не сразу понял, что такая строка является примером данных, но и так отработает как нужно :)